# How to use List<T>.Find() on a simple collection that does not implement Find()?

Tags: generics, c#-3.0

I want to use List.Find() on a simple collection that does not implement Find().
The naive way I thought of, is to just wrap it with a list and execute .Find(), like this:

```
ICollection myCows = GetAllCowsFromFarm(); // whatever the collection impl. is...
var steak = new List<Cow>(myCows).Find(moo => moo.Name == "La Vache qui Rit");
```

Now, 1st of all I'd like to know, C#-wise, what is the cost of this wrapping?
Is it still faster to 'for' this collection the traditional way?

Second, is there a better straightforward way elegantly use that .Find()?

Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`List<T>`, when constructed with an `IEnumerable` (i.e. your `ICollection`), copies the content. This could be expensive.

Do you have LINQ available? If so, you can use the `First` extension method, which returns the first match found (or throws an exception if there's no match). This will work on any `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
var cattle = GetAllCows();
var steak = cattle.First(moo => moo.Name == "La Vache qui Rit");
```

You can also use `Where`, which will return all the matches:

```
var cattle = GetAllCows();
var matches = cattle.Where(moo => moo.Name == "La Vache qui Rit");
```

There's a heap of useful extension methods in the `Enumerable` class. LINQ is not just for databases.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Enumerable.Where`:

```
var steak = myCows.Where(moo => moo.Name == "La Vache qui Rit");
```

This has the advantage of not costing you a complete copy of the collection.

EDIT: D'oh! @Roger's answer is better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use linq for this:

```
using System.Linq;

...

var steak = myCows.First(moo => moo.Name == "La Vache qui Rit");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll just add to you guys the use of .FirstOrDefault() to avoid exception, WDYT?